# TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined (line 8, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this problem after creating google form in the script editor.
I don't know why this problem exists. And I am completely beginner in programming, so I'll be very grateful for easy explanation.

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
  //response
  //getRespondentEmail();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
  var htmlText = html.getCode();
  Logger.log(htmlText);
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var subject = "Response Received";
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support.";
  var options = { htmlBody:htmlText }

  if (emailTo !== undefined) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options);
  }
}
```

Comment: It means `e` is undefined. Where and how do you call your `sendEmail` function?

Comment: How are you passing the `e` variable to the `sendEmail` function? Moreover, what is `e` supposed to represent in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with forms much so I played around with this just for the fun of it and I never saw a problem.

One of the things a lot of new posters often attempt is to run such a function from the script editor and because that does not generate the required event object 'e' then you get problems in the code because e is now undefined.  Any way this function was set up to capture the respondent email and the items on my form as well as the associated answer and post them into a spreadsheet.  I also added  a simple use of an templated html for sending contents in an email.

GS:

```
 function sendEmail(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(gssid);//Opening the spreadsheet containing form link
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Getting Item Titles and responses
  sh.clearContents();
  r.unshift(['Title','Response']);
  r.unshift(['Email:',e.response.getRespondentEmail()]);//respondent email
  sh.getRange(1,1,r.length,2).setValues(r);//Posting data to sheet1 in the open spreadsheet  
  let o=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email');
  o.email=e.response.getRespondentEmail();//inserting global variable into template for use in html file during evaluate() process
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, 'Test', '', {htmlBody:o.evaluate().getContent()});
}
```

HTML:

The respondent email is:

Sheet1 Post Table:

| Email: | Redacted |
| --- | --- |
| Title | Response |
| One | 1 |
| Two | 2 |

Emai:

[image]

> Don't forget this all runs off of a form submission

[image]